# Saving a record in a Lightning Component and wait for flows/processes/triggers to be executed before reload page

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, trigger, visual-workflow

I'm using a Lightning Component to upadte a SObjectType = **Task** record.
I'm using this one in particular:

```
component.find("editModal").get("e.recordSave").fire();
```

It works fine and the record is updated and then i reload the page.
I've tried both of these instruction to reload:

```
$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
```

And

```
location.reload();
```

**Problem:**

There are some flows starting with this record update and i need them to be finished before refreshing the view to the final user.

Is there any way to check if the record has been unlocked from any kind of execution?

ps. I've already disabled the *"Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance"* session preference.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The "editModal" component should tell your component when it's done saving. For the standard lightning:recordEditForm, that's the "onsuccess" event, for a custom component, you should modify it to include a similar action. Once you get notification that the record has saved, then you can refresh the data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

To show the record i'm using this:

<force:recordEdit aura:id="editModal" recordId="{!v.recordId"/>

how can i identify the event that the record has been successfully saved?

Comment: @gmemo force:recordEdit doesn't have such an event. Consider using lightning:recordEditForm instead.

Comment: i can't use lightning:recordEditForm because it's not supported by SObject Task.
I've solved this problem using <aura:handler name="onSaveSuccess" event="force:recordSaveSuccess" action="{!c.handleSaveSuccess}"/>, but now i've the same problem on catching the errors whichreally doesn't have an event.